# メタとモデレーターの意見に返答します

Tags: 討議

この投稿は、2020 年 3 月 4 日に JNat さんが Meta Stack Exchange に投稿した ["Our Commitment to Responding to Meta and Moderators"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344586) の和訳です。

---

[我々の Q1 ロードマップを示すブログ記事](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/02/25/sharing-our-first-quarter-2020-community-roadmap/)で Teresa が述べたとおり、Stack Exchange 社はメタサイトおよびモデレーターの意見に応じるため、新しいメタ参加ポリシーを決めるなどの取り組みを進めています。この取り組みの目的は、さまざまなメタサイト、特に Meta Stack Overflow と Meta Stack Exchange にスタッフが参加する頻度を高めることです。

我々が主にしなければいけないことは、スタッフの返答や対応が必要とされるようなコミュニティ・フィードバックに実際に返答したり対応したりできるようにすることです。この投稿では如何にしてこれを行うかを定めます。同時に我々が現実的に返答できる質問の数がどのくらいであるかを探り、内部的にも外部的にも合理的な決まりを作れるようにします。以下に書くのはその検証と目標決めのタイムラインです。

**コミュニティのフィードバックに対応するための新しい手順：**

スタッフの対応が必要とされると感じられたメタ質問に、スタッフやモデレーターが [調査中](/questions/tagged/%e8%aa%bf%e6%9f%bb%e4%b8%ad) タグをつけます。このタグは Network 上のどのメタサイトでも使えます（訳註：英語では status-review タグです）。Network 上でこのタグがついた質問は自動的に内部のトラッキングシステムに追加されます。

3 月 16 日までに、モデレーターがどういったときにこのタグを使うべきで、どういったときに使うべきでないかを説明するドキュメントを MSE へ CM チームが投稿します（**更新:** [3 月 12 日に投稿されました](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3285)）。またユーザーは、[調査中](/questions/tagged/%e8%aa%bf%e6%9f%bb%e4%b8%ad) タグがついてしかるべきだと思う投稿に対し、通報機能を使ってモデレーターやスタッフにタグをつけるか決めるよう促すことができます。

CM チームはモデレーターに対し、これらの決定ができる自信がもてるようサポートし、もしタグをつける規定に満たないと感じられる質問があれば丁寧にフィードバックを行います。この情報を元に、モデレーター向けのチュートリアルに詳細を足したり、モデレーターが疑問に対する回答を見つけられる所を紹介したりする予定です。

内部のトラッキングシステムに溜まった issue たちは、CM によって次のように管理されます。

- CM チームは MSO（および多言語版の MSO）、MSE、そして Moderator Team においてタグ付けされた質問を優先します。
- MSO や MSE 以外のメタにおける質問については、時間の許す限り対応します。

この過程において CM チームは[電話交換手](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switchboard_operator)のように振る舞います。つまり、それぞれの issue が内部の適切なチームへ引き渡されるようにします。同様に、そのチームからの情報をコミュニティに流す役割も CM チームが担います。

モデレーターは Moderator Team においてモデレーター特有の決まりやツールについての質問をスタッフに引き渡せます。この場合も上で説明したように処理されます。

**タイムライン：**

- **今から 3 月 15 日までに**、CM チームが上に書いた手順を確立し、必要な内部システムを作ります。同時に他のチームから要求される決まりも決めます。
- **3 月 16 日から 4 月 30 日までに**、この手順を検証します：新しくメタに投稿された質問は [調査中](/questions/tagged/%e8%aa%bf%e6%9f%bb%e4%b8%ad) タグをつけることができます。これらの質問はトラッキングシステムに入り、CM チームが分類して社内の適切な所へ送り、返答をメタに返します。全てのメタサイトにおいてどのくらいスタッフの助けが必要とされたかのデータを収集します。
- **5 月 15日**、CM チームが検証結果を報告します。この検証に基づき、どのくらいの量の投稿にどのくらいの素早さで我々が返答できるかを決めます。
- 最適な値を保つため、この目標値は四半期ごとに見直されます。現実的な目標を定め、それを満たしていきたいからです。

**コミュニケーション：**

毎月の様子をお知らせするための質問投稿を CM チームが行います。この投稿では以下のような統計や情報が載せられる予定です：

- 毎月どのくらいの数の投稿に [調査中] タグがついたか。
- それがどのタイプの質問だったか（1位のタグ）。
- それにいくつ返答して、その返答にかかった時間の中央値はいくつか。
- いくつが処理中か。
- いくつが中断されたか。

この統計と共に、特筆すべきもの、興味深いもの、面白いものなど、スタッフの返答のハイライトを書きます。定期的にこの情報が見れることで、メタと共に歩むやり方を強調し、Network 上での体験を向上させるために我々スタッフが何をしたか注意を惹けると願っています。

この取り組みは内部的には我々のための検証であると共に、コミュニティやモデレーターにとっての検証でもあります。もしこの検証の中でモデレーターに通報された質問の数が（MSO や MSE のように）扱えないほど多くなってしまったら、何かしら緩和できるよう CM チームが動きます。検証の中期や後期で方向性を整えるかもしれません。この意味で、タグ付けリクエストを大量に行うのは避けていただくようお願いします。特に何年も前のものを持ってくるのはやめてください。

やり方に関するここまでの説明で、我々がコミュニティと共に歩むための一歩であることが分かりやすく示されていれば幸いです。もし質問があれば、回答として投稿してください。しっかりとお答えします（訳註：これは[元の投稿](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344586)へ英語で回答するか、ここに回答されたものをどなたかが英訳して元の投稿に回答するかになります）。我々が MSE や他のメタによりたくさん現れ、我々と皆さんの間の信頼関係を再構築できると期待しています。

---

> 補足：タグをつけたい質問を、検証期間が始まるより前に通報するのはおやめください。

Comment: 日本語版のみ利用していると気づきにくいですが、背景として「Stack Exchange社はコミュニティの声を蔑ろにしているんじゃないか？」という不信感からいわゆる "炎上" 状態にあることを受けた、SE社からの一つの回答ということのようです。 - [Firing mods and forced relicensing: is Stack Exchange still interested in cooperating with the community?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333965) / なお、entoさんがQiitaに詳しいまとめを書かれています。 - [Stack Exchangeメタは何故炎上しているか](https://qiita.com/ento/items/e06ed572971db201a89d)