# 新しい返答方法のためのガイドライン：コミュニティとモデレーターによる問題報告のやり方（2020年3月）

Tags: 討議

この投稿は、2020 年 3 月 12 日にJNat さんが Meta Stack Exchange へ投稿した ["Community and Moderator guidelines for escalating issues via new response process (March 2020)"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345032/341401) の和訳です。

元投稿は随時更新される予定であるため、古い情報になっている可能性にご注意ください。コミュニティ wiki として投稿するため、もし古くなっていたら更新していただければ幸いです。

---

先週私は、メタとモデレーターに対して返答することを約束する旨の[投稿をしました](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3284)。もしまだこの投稿を読んでいなければ先に読むことをオススメします。先の記事は我々の企業が約束したいことの概観になっているからです。おおよそ次のことを書きました：

- CM チームの作った、コミュニティからのフィードバックを受けるための新しいやり方について紹介しました。
- このやり方のための検証タイムラインを示し、それが 2020 年 3 月 16 日から 2020 年 4 月 30 日までとしました。
- この検証にまつわって予定されているコミュニケーションについて大枠を示しました。

その投稿で約束されていたように、この投稿ではスタッフの手が必要だと感じられた問題についてモデレーターがいつスタッフに引き渡すべきでいつしないべきなのかのガイドを書きます。また同様にコミュニティ全体にとってのガイドも行い、どんな場合にモデレーターの注意を惹くべきなのかを説明します。このガイドは検証期間の間のみ有効であり、終了後には見直され更新される予定です。

モデレーター向けには、[Moderator Team に類似の投稿があり](https://stackoverflow.com/c/moderators/q/2629/289)、モデレーターがどのように問題を引き渡すのか解説しています。その投稿は Network 全体のモデレーターが今回のやり方について議論したり、特定の投稿が引き渡される対象かどうか議論したりするための場としても使っていただけます。

## どんな質問を引き渡すべきですか？

#### 新しい質問：

「検証期間中に投稿された新しい質問（2020 年 3 月 16 日以降に投稿されたすべて）」については、以下の条件を参考にしてください：

- それは機能の要求をする質問で、コミュニティの支持を集めていますか？
- それは他の方も再現できるバグの報告ですか？
- それは Stack Exchange の社員でないと完璧に答えられない質問ですか？

上記のうち**ひとつでも**当てはまっているなら、引き渡すのに適した質問です。

#### 古い質問：

もちろん、Network 上のさまざまなメタにおいて、注目されているものの未だスタッフの返答が無い投稿もたくさんあるでしょう。いくつかはずっとずっと昔に投稿されて放っておかれているものまであります。しかし CM チームがそれらによっていっぱいいっぱいになってしまわないようバランスをとるため、また、今回の検証では眼中におかないようにするため、代わりに次のようにすることを提案します。つまり、何かしらコミュニティ・マネージャーだけが答えられるようなものか、現在どこかのプロダクト・チームが取り組んでいるものにあたるような古い質問のみに注目していただきたいです（このように限定することで古い議論を見つけやすくし、今回の調査に使えるようにします）。

したがって、もしある投稿が上に書いた新しい質問向けの条件を満たしているものの検証が始まる前（2020 年 3 月 16 日より前）に投稿されたものであるならば、以下のうちのどれかになっているかどうか確認してください。なっていれば、スタッフへ引き渡すのに適した候補です。

- **コミュニティ特有の悩み事**：コミュニティの決まり事からガイドまで、コミュニティ・マネージャーでないと上手く対処できないようなものすべて。たとえばヘルプセンターのページに関するものなど、新しく開発する必要の無い変更などを含みます。
- **クローズ機能の UX**：質問のクローズに関する一般的な体験や仕組みに関する投稿。現在のシステムだと質問者、回答者、レビュー者、あるいはモデレーターが直面するような問題一般。機能要求や提案など。（これは我々の [Q1 ロードマップ](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/02/25/sharing-our-first-quarter-2020-community-roadmap/)で言及されており、[Q2 のプランが共有された際により詳細が書かれる予定](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344178/the-q1-2020-community-roadmap-is-on-the-blog/344209#comment1153412_344183)です。）
- **質問のフォロー**：我々はこの機能についてその内詳しいメタ投稿をしフィードバックを求める予定です。しかし、もし質問のお気に入り機能やフォロー機能、興味のある質問の通知を受ける機能、通知をオフにしてノイズを減らす機能などなどについて既存の機能要求や一般的なフィードバック、欠点の指摘などがあれば候補になります。
- **Onebox**：[Stack Overflow for Teams と GitHub を統合する機能である onebox](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394055) は他との統合も念頭に起きつつ作られ、他の（公開されている）Q&A サイトにも広げていく目的もありました。Q&A における一般の onebox にまつわる質問は良い候補です。他にも、質問中のコードスニペットに関するものやその他の開発ツールとの統合に関するもの、ソースコードや質問が変化していく中で質問の精度を保つための問題なども OK です。
- **就職採用管理**：我々は採用申し込み履歴ページについて改善を行っているところです。このため https://stackoverflow.com/jobs に関係する質問は候補です。

上のいくつかは SO 特有のものですが、残りは最終的には Network のサイト全体に適用されるものです（最近の新しい「質問する」ページのように、いくらかシンプルになるかもしれませんが）。これらの大きな項目に加えて、Network にある SO や MSE 以外のそれぞれのサイトについて、それぞれのコミュニティで今までに独自に有効化されている機能についても何かあれば知りたいです。たとえば MathJax やシンタックスハイライトなどです。また[新しい参加者の助けになるような個別の警告](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344513)も気になります。あなたのサイト特有の機能のうち特に目立つものトップ 5 を挙げ、ポジティブに受け入れられているものについての質問は候補です。ただし、開発の時間を要するような機能やあなたのサイトひとつだけにしか適用されないものは高い優先度が与えられにくいです。

それと、蛇足かとは思いますが明言しておきますと、**今回の方法を使って注意を惹くために古い質問を再投稿するのはどうかおやめください。**

## 通常のユーザーがスタッフの注意を惹くためにはどうすれば良いですか？

もしある質問が上記の条件を満たしているのであれば、通報機能の「モデレーターによる対応が必要です」を使ってモデレーターに連絡してください。文脈が分かるよう、この投稿へのリンクを張ってください。なぜその投稿が候補になりうるのか、なるべく明快に説明してください。

**通報によって[モデレーターがオーバーフローする](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJ6HM.gif)のを防ぐため、通報爆撃はやめてください。**CM Team は（心の中で……？）最初の波に備え、それが検証から数週間後にはおそらく（予想通りなら？）減るであろうと思っていますが、モデレーターはそのようなものに対処する人々の最前線にいることをどうかご承知おきください。CM はモデレーターの負担が急に増えないよう働きかけ、なるべく楽になるよう調整しますが、皆さんがタグ付けリクエストを連打しないことにも依存しています。

## モデレーターがスタッフの注意を惹くためにはどうすれば良いですか？

#### モデレーターは通報の中からどうやって投稿を選べば良いですか？

上記のガイドにしたがい、どの投稿が良い候補になるか選んでください。また、通常の通報を処理するときと同じ判断基準も使ってください。通報自体は helpful だけどもタグの追加は不要だと思う場合があるかもしれませんが、それで構いません。あなたのいつもの判断を行ってください。もしタグを追加しなかった場合、通報の返信機能を使い、通報者がその決定について何かしら情報が得られるようにしてみてください。

上で述べたように、最初の間は大量の通報が来るかもしれません。このことを考えると、最初の内は大量の投稿がスタッフへ引き渡されるでしょう。それで構いません。

もし断言できないことがあれば、他のモデレーターと相談したり、Teachers' Lounge で CM に ping してください。必要以上に引き渡される問題よりかは、必要よりも少なくなってしまう問題の方が深刻です。もしスタッフへ流さなくても回答できる問題だと CM チームが判断した場合、モデレーターに回答があるであろう場所を教え、このガイドを見直す良い機会です。

もし [調査中](/questions/tagged/%e8%aa%bf%e6%9f%bb%e4%b8%ad) タグをつけることにした後なにかしらの要因でそれが解決した場合、たとえば、本来であればコミュニティの誰かがその問題に回答できる状態であった場合や、バグの原因がユーザー側にあった場合などは、Teachers' Lounge で CM に ping し、状況を説明してください。その後、その特定の問題についてどうすべきか解明します（少なくともタグは外すことになるでしょう）。

#### では、実際本当に引き渡すとなればどうすれば良いですか？

ただ [調査中](/questions/tagged/%e8%aa%bf%e6%9f%bb%e4%b8%ad) タグをつけてください。そうすることで我々の内部のトラッキングシステムにその投稿がフィードとしてのせられます。

モデレーターは、上記の条件を読み、もしある投稿がこれを満たすならタグをつけてください（通常のユーザーのように通報する段階を踏まなくて良いです）。

もしその投稿に既に [調査中](/questions/tagged/%e8%aa%bf%e6%9f%bb%e4%b8%ad) タグがついているなら、Teachers' Lounge で CM に ping してください。我々が手動でその投稿をシステムに追加します。

## 引き渡されたあとどうなるのでしょうか？

CM チームがその投稿に優先度をつけ、それぞれ関連するチーム（CM や関連するプロダクトチーム）に送ります。その後そのチームの今まで通りのワークフローのもと、なるべく早く回答できるように処理されます。

今回の目的は可能な限り多くの投稿に反応を返すことであって、これは回答をすることやコメントを残すこと、あるいは別の status タグを付けることなどを意図しています。必ずしも何かしらの機能を実装したりバグを直したりするのが意図されている訳ではないです。もちろんそうなる場合もあるでしょうが。

一部の投稿は反応なしのままになります。それがどのくらいの量あるのか記録をつけ、検証が終わったあと報告します。これによって、我々がどのくらいの数の投稿にどのくらいの早さで対処できるのかの目標を決めやすくします。その後この目標を四半期ごとに見直し、現実的な目標を立てた上でそれを満たします。

---

このガイドが充分分かりやすければ幸いです。このやり方が[我々の検証したい手法](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3284/19110)のゴールを達成するためのものになると信じています。この投稿は元の投稿についていた目立った質問の多くに答えるものにもなっていることでしょう。今回の取り組みは我々にとってもコミュニティやモデレーターにとっても検証ですから、よく分からないところや混乱したところがあれば、回答として投稿してください（訳註：[元の投稿](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345032/341401)に英語で投稿するか、この投稿についたものをどなたかが英訳して投稿するかになります）。この手法自体についてや、今後のガイドについてのフィードバックも歓迎です。

Comment: 未訳ですが、4月分の統計結果が出ました https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/347959/341401